# Looking for ETCD-Metrics interpretation

Tags: database, timestamp, monitoring, metrics, etcd

I'm looking for an Explanation of the ETCD-Metrics result, i run the following Command:

`curl -L http://localhost:2379/metrics`

Part of the result would be something like this:

```
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.002"} 819
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.004"} 1.3400495e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.008"} 1.7852494e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.016"} 1.8745663e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.032"} 1.8788077e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.064"} 1.87975e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.128"} 1.8808099e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.256"} 1.8813756e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.512"} 1.8820377e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="1.024"} 1.8823831e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="2.048"} 1.8823904e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="4.096"} 1.882392e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="8.192"} 1.8823939e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf"} 1.8823948e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_sum 85016.59519294072
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_count 1.8823948e+07
```

Could anyone please help me interpreting the previous result? like what does "le" stands for? what does the number after "le=" represent? what are the "sum" and "count" lines represent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“le” stands for “less than”

```
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.002"} 819
```

means
`there are 918 requests whose etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration is less than 0.002s(2ms)`

```
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="8.192"} 1.8823939e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf"} 1.8823948e+07
1.8823948e+07  - 1.8823939e+07 = 9
```

Which means
`there are 9 requests which cost more than 8.192s`

```
+Inf is infinity
```

le="+Inf" means all

If value{le="1.024"} is same with value{le="+Inf"}, it means no request costs more than 1s which shows that the disk is not bad. etcd expect disk sync is less than 500ms.

```
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="1.024"} 1.8823948e+07
etcd_disk_wal_fsync_duration_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf"} 1.8823948e+07
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this was really helpful! I appreciate it.
Do you know maybe the difference between "sum" and "count" sections?

Comment: @icy3 sum/count is the average duration of etcd_disk_wal_fsync.

count is the same with {le="+Inf"} all. 

sum is all duration sum

Comment: Thanks dude! your answer was helpful!